# When i write this line to flex code,i am getting this error :

Tags: file, apache-flex, file-io, adobe, flex3

When I write this line to flex code,i am getting this error :
Multiple markers at this line:

-1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: File.

-1120: Access of undefined property File.

-Access of undefined property File

-Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: File

```
var dir : File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("MyFolder");
```

Comment: imported `flash.filesystem`??. Looks like `File` class is only available with AIR Runtime. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Comment: My mind was going the same place where @SakthiKumar's was.  Are you building an AIR app?  IF not; you can't use the File class.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as they said in the comments the File class is only to be used in AIR applications.

You can't access the files of a client from a browser based flash/flex application.

You're only allowed to store flash cookies (local sharedObjects) and if you wan't the users to upload a file they need to do that through a flash.net.FileReference

good luck